# Why Geofire does not work on iOS ? - Ionic

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic3, geofire

I’m developing an app with the ionic framework v3. My app uses Firebase and Geofire plugins to locate some points on a Google map.
App works fine for Android devices and Browsers but for iOS, nothing happens. The map is loaded but there is no marker. I think that the Geofire callback events are not called because console.log() are not printed.

I have no idea where the error is because code works for other OS…

Furthermore, when I launch the Geofire process, I have these logs in the Xcode console, but I don’t know if it is has a link with my problem.

```
2019-03-25 18:33:34.485252+0100 XXX[1540:17125] GOOGLE-MAP : ngAfterInit
2019-03-25 18:33:34.630989+0100 XXX[1540:17125] TABS : ionViewDidEnter
2019-03-25 18:33:34.631244+0100 XXX[1540:17125] CREATING GEOQUERY AND CALLBACKS
2019-03-25 18:33:34.642649+0100 XXX[1540:17125] GEOQUERY : {"_firebaseRef":"https://XXX.firebaseio.com/geofire","_callbacks":{"ready":[null],"key_entered":[null],"key_exited":[],"key_moved":[]},"_cancelled":false,"_currentGeohashesQueried":{"u0ts:u0tw":{"active":true},"u0th:u0tn":{"active":true},"u0td:u0th":{"active":true},"u0t4:u0t8":{"active":true}},"_locationsTracked":{},"_valueEventFired":false,"_geohashCleanupScheduled":false,"_cleanUpCurrentGeohashesQueriedTimeout":null,"_cleanUpCurrentGeohashesQueriedInterval":33,"_center":[48.5734053,7.7521113],"_radius":20,"_outstandingGeohashReadyEvents":["u0ts:u0tw","u0th:u0tn","u0td:u0th","u0t4:u0t8"]}
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96ADFD77-33B6-4FB1-B9C3-7B0EAA87491E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EB22A255-929F-4C73-8BF1-39EE14D54CA0/XXX.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96ADFD77-33B6-4FB1-B9C3-7B0EAA87491E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EB22A255-929F-4C73-8BF1-39EE14D54CA0/XXX.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96ADFD77-33B6-4FB1-B9C3-7B0EAA87491E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EB22A255-929F-4C73-8BF1-39EE14D54CA0/XXX.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/StorageWithTileProto.omo'
2019-03-25 18:33:34.758165+0100 XXX[1540:17399] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
2019-03-25 18:33:34.928257+0100 XXX[1540:17405] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
2019-03-25 18:33:35.149019+0100 XXX[1540:17125] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll
2019-03-25 18:33:36.029352+0100 XXX[1540:17242] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1.1:2][0x7fb2cc408570] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-25 18:33:36.029663+0100 XXX[1540:17242] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1.1:2][0x7fb2cc408570] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-25 18:33:36.029960+0100 XXX[1540:17242] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-03-25 18:33:36.030085+0100 XXX[1540:17242] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-03-25 18:33:36.076358+0100 XXX[1540:17125] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 2.7.30514.0
2019-03-25 18:33:36.076595+0100 XXX[1540:17125] New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 3.0.33124.0
2019-03-25 18:33:40.383077+0100 XXX[1540:17398] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
2019-03-25 18:33:40.583666+0100 XXX[1540:17227] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1.1:2][0x7fb2c9f7a120] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-25 18:33:40.583865+0100 XXX[1540:17227] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1.1:2][0x7fb2c9f7a120] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-25 18:33:40.584583+0100 XXX[1540:17227] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
2019-03-25 18:33:40.584711+0100 XXX[1540:17227] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
```

Here is the code that creates and manages GeoFire.

```
refreshResto() {

    console.log("CREATING GEOQUERY AND CALLBACKS");

    // Cancel previous geoQuery
    if (typeof this.geoQuery !== "undefined")
        this.geoQuery.cancel();

    this.geoQuery = this.geoFire.query({
        center: [this.variablesService.mapPosition.lat, this.variablesService.mapPosition.lng],
        radius: 20
    });

    let key_entered = false;

    // Called when a point is discovered by the query
    this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
        key_entered = true;

        console.log("QUERY ON"); // Never printed on iOS

        // Some processing
        // ...
    });

    // Called when geoQuery ends his init process
    this.geoQuery.on("ready", () => {
        console.log("READY !!"); // Never printed on iOS
        if (!key_entered)
            // ...
        else
            // ...
    });

    console.log("GEOQUERY : " + JSON.stringify(this.geoQuery));
}
```

I don't think the problem is in the code, perhaps in config files or it is a plugin's problem.
Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have updated my post with the code with Geofire inside.  I hope this will help you understand the problem.